# Over voltage GPIO in STM32F

Tags: voltage, stm32, gpio

I have a STM32F427 micro controller with 2.5 V power supply. Some input signals are 3.3 V. Does it cause any damage on GPIO or can the STM32F427 tolerate 3.3 V logic?

Comment: What does the datasheet tell you?

Comment: I read the datasheet, tried to find the info. It's completely crap, I understand why Amir can't find the info, and I'm not going to suffer through the unstructured data-dump they call a datasheet. From what I could see, the I/O should only be used with VDD+0.3, but can perhaps be operated higher if you disable the pullups. Not sure. Hopefully someone else can clarify.

Comment: Some STM32s have 5V-tolerant inputs, for some of the GPIO ports.  Not sure about STM32F427 though. @pipe has accurately described the ST datasheet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The datasheet is here:

http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/03/b4/b2/36/4c/72/49/29/DM00071990.pdf/files/DM00071990.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00071990.pdf

From page 52:[image]

So if look for I/O pins in the table that have I/O structure "FT".  These can tolerate inputs of up to 5V.  (This appears to be most of the I/O pins.)

I learned this procedure from this Olimex forum post: https://www.olimex.com/forum/index.php?topic=1301.msg6060#msg6060